# Pandas subtract value from one dataframe from columns in another dataframe depending on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like the ones below, let's call them df1 and df2 respectively.

```
state                 year    val1
ALABAMA               2012    22.186789
                      2016    27.725147
                      2020    25.461653
ALASKA                2012    13.988918
                      2016    14.730641
                      2020    10.061191
ARIZONA               2012     9.064766
                      2016     3.543962
                      2020    -0.308710
```

```
year    val2
2000    -0.491702
2004     2.434132
2008    -7.399984
2012    -3.935184
2016    -2.181941
2020    -4.448889
```

For each row in df1, I want to subtract val2 in df2 from every corresponding year in df1. I.e., I want to find the difference between val1 and val2 for each year in every state.

The dataframe I am trying to obtain is

```
party_simplified            val1      difference
state                year                      
ALABAMA              2012  22.186789  26.121973
                     2016  27.725147  29.907088
                     2020  25.461653  29.910542
ALASKA               2012  13.988918  17.924102
                     2016  14.730641  16.912582
                     2020  10.061191  14.510080
ARIZONA              2012   9.064766  12.999950
                     2016   3.543962   5.725903
                     2020  -0.308710   4.140180
```

I have been able to accomplish this using a for loop like the one below, but am wondering if there is a more efficient way.

```
for i in range(2012, 2024, 4):
    df1.loc[(slice(None), i), 'difference'] = df1.loc[(slice(None), i), 'val1'] - df2.loc[i]['val2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, though you might need to tweak it based on how your indices are set up:

```
merged = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, left_on='year', right_index=True)
df_new = (merged
          .assign(**{'difference': merged.val1 - merged.val2})
          .set_index(['state', 'year'])
          .filter(['val1', 'difference'])
          .sort_index())
df_new

                     val1   difference
state      year         
ALABAMA     2012    22.186789   26.121973
            2016    27.725147   29.907088
            2020    25.461653   29.910542
ALASKA      2012    13.988918   17.924102
            2016    14.730641   16.912582
            2020    10.061191   14.510080
ARIZONA     2012    9.064766    12.999950
            2016    3.543962    5.725903
            2020    -0.308710   4.140179
```